# LSTM - What kind of data should contain every dimension of input LSTM matrix, where does specific dimension points to?

Tags: long-short-term-memory

I am a beginner and I have a hard time understanding inputs and outputs of LSTM.

So from the begining, I am trying to create multivariate input&output LSTM for time series forecasting.
Thankfully I've managed to operate on multivariate inputs&outputs, but, what I don't understand are the indices and what is stored in them.

For example, I have an intial input 2d numpy array of 4 variables:

```
a  b  c  d
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

Lets say that the shape of this array is 5000x4 - thus 4 features and 5000 rows,
So for the LSTM input I'd need an array of `x_train = (samples, timesteps, 4 features)`,
And the code for input is as following:

```
   model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 4]),
    ...
    keras.layers.Dense(4)
])
```

Also since I want 4 features as output I need 4 output neurons.

Now for example my `y_train` values are in the following array:

```
y_train = (samples, timesteps, 4 features)
```

Now I'd like to understand in what dimension (samples, timesteps or 4 features) in x_train should be values from inital array?
To what values timesteps dimension points, same question about samples and features.

Now let's say I've trained my model, from the output and I get predictions array of the same dimensions as `x_train` and `y_train`, in what dimension are the exact predictions?
Since I'd like to plot them or something with them?

EDIT: Additional question
What type of data should be stored in samples, timesteps, features.
Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: Rather than writing "Need help understanding X and doing Y", can you please just put your **specific** question in the title?

Comment: @nbro done, hope it's ok